# @Qualifier on interface

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-framework-beans

I have read in a question that an @Qualifier annotation can be on top of interface.

But I do not know how to build this.

What I have tried is something like:

```java
interface I1 {
}

@Qualifier("qi2")
interface I2 extends I1 {
}

@Qualifier("qi3")
interface I3 extends I1 {
}

@Component
class C2 implements I2 {
}

@Component
class C3 implements I3 {
}

@Component
class HolderC {
    HolderC(@Qualifier("qi3") I1 a) {
        System.out.println(a.getClass());
    }
}
```

But it says that :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'pack1.I1' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("qi3")}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1654)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    ... 14 more
```

I would have expected to work.

I also had a look at the bean c2 in the application context and there is no qualifier on that bean.

**What could I do to have the @Qualifier annotation on top of an interface?**

Answer (score 0):

@Qualifier is used whenever there are multiple beans available of an interface and we are trying to Autowire it. We can't pass it in the functions. In your case, we can proceed like below:

```
interface I1 {
}

interface I2 extends I1 {
}

interface I3 extends I1 {
}

@Component
@Qualifier("qi2")
class C2 implements I2 {
}

@Component
@Qualifier("qi3")
class C3 implements I3 {
}

@Component
class HolderC {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("qi3")
    I1 a;

    HolderC() {
        System.out.println(a.getClass());
    }
}
```